# MySql: Concatenate column where there are duplicates

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have the following query:

```
SELECT Number, Concat(Product,' ',Division) as 'Product', 
count(*) as 'COUNT', SUM(tta) as 'TTA', ROUND(SUM(tta) / count(*),2) as 'AVG' 
FROM cdrdata cdr 
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.Number = cdr.calling 
LEFT JOIN divisions d ON d.id = p.DivisionID 
WHERE CustomerID = 32 AND p.Status = 1 
Group by calling
ORDER BY Product;
```

Results:
From this:

```
Product1 DIvision1
Product1 Division2
Product2 Division3
Product3 Division4
```

To this:

```
Product1 Division1
Product1 Division2
Product2
Product3
```

**Q:** How can I modify my query so it would concatenate `Product` and `Division` only where there are duplicate `Products` and show the duplicates as well, like above example?

Comment: may be adding an having clause after `group by` as `having count(*) > 1` note that the `group by` needs to be on `product`

Comment: I need to show the duplicates also, just to concatenate only on duplicates

Comment: try as `case when count(*) > 1 then Concat(Product,' ',Division) else Product end as 'Product'`

Comment: that doesn't work...

Comment: @alex: It does work you just might need to use [a derived table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/ansi-diff-subqueries.html).

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Use `group_concat()` of MySQL

The query is as follows:

```
mysql> SELECT  group_concat(product,' ',division SEPARATOR '\n') as products FROM pd GROUP BY product HAVING count(product) > 1;
+---------------------------------------+
| products                              |
+---------------------------------------+
| Product1 Division1
Product1 Division2 |
+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

There is no sufficient data provided about the whole data set so I have worked only with the concatenation part.

pd is the name of the table. The contents are:

```
mysql> select * from pd;
+----------+-----------+
| product  | division  |
+----------+-----------+
| Product1 | Division1 |
| Product1 | Division2 |
| Product2 | Division3 |
| Product3 | Division4 |
+----------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

An another version of the query with the help of @DaveRandom as follows:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM pd a INNER JOIN pd b ON a.product = b.product AND a.division <> b.division;

mysql> SELECT DISTINCT a.* FROM pd a INNER JOIN pd b ON a.product = b.product AND a.division <> b.division;
+----------+-----------+
| product  | division  |
+----------+-----------+
| Product1 | Division2 |
| Product1 | Division1 |
+----------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```